# Where should I ask questions on telephony?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask about telephony a services and implementation of ISP, how to set up automatic SMS, and other questions?

Answer (score 2):

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com would seem a good bet, at least about the ISP/Network side of things.

> Ask about...

> - Specific issues with network engineering
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
> - Operating, maintaining, purchasing or managing an enterprise / service provider network
> - Planning or designing an enterprise / service provider network
> - Model or product line features and differences
> - Lab scenarios involving on-topic equipment
> - Tools used by network professionals
> - Servers operating as a router/switch/firewall
> - Design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (IP, TCP, routing protocols, STP, etc.)
> - Content delivery networks
> - Production troubleshooting or problem resolution
> - Physical infrastructure (standard color coding of cables, types of fiber, etc)
> - Implementing and enforcing network security or policies

> Caveats:
>
> - Networks must be under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to answer your question)
> - Hardware that has a paid support option from the manufacturer (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class devices)